Sort Polars Dataframe columns based on row data
I have this data:
import polars as pl

pl.DataFrame({
    'region': ['EU', 'ASIA', 'AMER', 'Year'],
    'Share': [99, 6, -30, 2020],
    'Ration': [70, 4, -10, 2019],
    'Lots': [70, 4, -10, 2018],
    'Stake': [80, 5, -20, 2021],
})
# shape: (4, 5)
# ┌────────┬───────┬────────┬──────┬───────┐
# │ region ┆ Share ┆ Ration ┆ Lots ┆ Stake │
# │ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
# │ str    ┆ i64   ┆ i64    ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
# ╞════════╪═══════╪════════╪══════╪═══════╡
# │ EU     ┆ 99    ┆ 70     ┆ 70   ┆ 80    │
# │ ASIA   ┆ 6     ┆ 4      ┆ 4    ┆ 5     │
# │ AMER   ┆ -30   ┆ -10    ┆ -10  ┆ -20   │
# │ Year   ┆ 2020  ┆ 2019   ┆ 2018 ┆ 2021  │
# └────────┴───────┴────────┴──────┴───────┘

I want to order the columns based on the Year row, while leaving the region column first. So ideally I am looking for this:
shape: (4, 5)
┌────────┬──────┬────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ region ┆ Lots ┆ Ration ┆ Share ┆ Stake │
│ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64  ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪══════╪════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ EU     ┆ 70   ┆ 70     ┆ 99    ┆ 80    │
│ ASIA   ┆ 4    ┆ 4      ┆ 6     ┆ 5     │
│ AMER   ┆ -10  ┆ -10    ┆ -30   ┆ -20   │
│ Year   ┆ 2018 ┆ 2019   ┆ 2020  ┆ 2021  │
└────────┴──────┴────────┴───────┴───────┘

How can this be achieved? I tried using polars' sort function, but could not get it to do what I needed.

Have you tried to switch column and row orientation? This can be done with a paramter in the Dataframe's __init__. Because usually and it seems also polars, has the assumption that per row there is one Data-Entity and not per Column. If you can not do that. I suggest you have to create a new Dataframe and do the sorting logic at your own. But I am not familiar with polars, maybe there are some hacks.

.sort() works on rows.
You could reshape with .unpivot(), .sort() and then .pivot() back to the wide format.
(df.with_row_index()
   .unpivot(index=["index", "region"])
   .sort(pl.col("value").filter(region="Year").first().over("variable"))
   .pivot("variable", index="region", values="value")
)

shape: (4, 5)
┌────────┬──────┬────────┬───────┬───────┐
│ region ┆ Lots ┆ Ration ┆ Share ┆ Stake │
│ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64  ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪══════╪════════╪═══════╪═══════╡
│ EU     ┆ 70   ┆ 70     ┆ 99    ┆ 80    │
│ ASIA   ┆ 4    ┆ 4      ┆ 6     ┆ 5     │
│ AMER   ┆ -10  ┆ -10    ┆ -30   ┆ -20   │
│ Year   ┆ 2018 ┆ 2019   ┆ 2020  ┆ 2021  │
└────────┴──────┴────────┴───────┴───────┘

Or do it at the "Python level" and sort the Series by their last value.
df.select(
    "region", 
    *sorted(df.drop("region"), key=pl.Series.last)
)



I tried using polars' sort function, but could not get it to do what I needed.

To be frank, why things may not be working nicely is due to the layout of your data. Specifically the year row at the bottom. "Year" is not a region, nor are the years genuine values in the other columns.
You would likely find a layout like this a lot easier to work with.
pl.DataFrame({
    "region": ["EU", "ASIA", "AMER"] * 4,
    "year": [2018] * 3 + [2019] * 3 + [2020] * 3 + [2021] * 3,
    "variable": ["Lots"] * 3 + ["Ration"] * 3 + ["Share"] * 3 + ["Stake"] * 3,
    "value": [70, 4, -10, 70, 4, -10, 99, 6, -30, 80, 5, -10]
})

shape: (12, 4)
┌────────┬──────┬──────────┬───────┐
│ region ┆ year ┆ variable ┆ value │
│ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64  ┆ str      ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪══════╪══════════╪═══════╡
│ EU     ┆ 2018 ┆ Lots     ┆ 70    │
│ ASIA   ┆ 2018 ┆ Lots     ┆ 4     │
│ AMER   ┆ 2018 ┆ Lots     ┆ -10   │
│ EU     ┆ 2019 ┆ Ration   ┆ 70    │
│ ASIA   ┆ 2019 ┆ Ration   ┆ 4     │
│ AMER   ┆ 2019 ┆ Ration   ┆ -10   │
│ EU     ┆ 2020 ┆ Share    ┆ 99    │
│ ASIA   ┆ 2020 ┆ Share    ┆ 6     │
│ AMER   ┆ 2020 ┆ Share    ┆ -30   │
│ EU     ┆ 2021 ┆ Stake    ┆ 80    │
│ ASIA   ┆ 2021 ┆ Stake    ┆ 5     │
│ AMER   ┆ 2021 ┆ Stake    ┆ -10   │
└────────┴──────┴──────────┴───────┘

This will get you there from what you have now, if your example is how you are receiving input
(
    df.unpivot(index="region")
   .group_by("variable")
   .agg(
       pl.col("value").filter(pl.col("region") == pl.lit("Year")).max().alias("year"),
       pl.struct("region", "value").filter(pl.col("region") != pl.lit("Year")),
    )
   .explode("region")
   .unnest("region")
   
)

or if you really need Lots, Ration, Share, Stake as columns, this layout is another alternative.
pl.DataFrame({
    'region': ["EU"] * 4 + ["ASIA"] * 4 + ["AMER"] * 4,
    'Lots': [70, None, None, None, 4, None, None, None, -10, None, None, None],
    'Ration': [None, 70, None, None, None, 4, None, None, None, -10, None, None],
    'Share': [None, None, 99, None, None, None, 6, None, None, None, -30, None],
    'Stake': [None, None, None, 80, None, None, None, 5, None, None, None, -10],
    "year": [2018, 2019, 2020, 2021] * 3,
})

shape: (12, 6)
┌────────┬──────┬────────┬───────┬───────┬──────┐
│ region ┆ Lots ┆ Ration ┆ Share ┆ Stake ┆ year │
│ ---    ┆ ---  ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---  │
│ str    ┆ i64  ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64   ┆ i64  │
╞════════╪══════╪════════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════╡
│ EU     ┆ 70   ┆ null   ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 2018 │
│ EU     ┆ null ┆ 70     ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 2019 │
│ EU     ┆ null ┆ null   ┆ 99    ┆ null  ┆ 2020 │
│ EU     ┆ null ┆ null   ┆ null  ┆ 80    ┆ 2021 │
│ ASIA   ┆ 4    ┆ null   ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 2018 │
│ ASIA   ┆ null ┆ 4      ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 2019 │
│ ASIA   ┆ null ┆ null   ┆ 6     ┆ null  ┆ 2020 │
│ ASIA   ┆ null ┆ null   ┆ null  ┆ 5     ┆ 2021 │
│ AMER   ┆ -10  ┆ null   ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 2018 │
│ AMER   ┆ null ┆ -10    ┆ null  ┆ null  ┆ 2019 │
│ AMER   ┆ null ┆ null   ┆ -30   ┆ null  ┆ 2020 │
│ AMER   ┆ null ┆ null   ┆ null  ┆ -10   ┆ 2021 │
└────────┴──────┴────────┴───────┴───────┴──────┘


If amount of columns is not large, I'd probably sort columns based on Year row and then select them accordingly:
cols = sorted(
    df.filter(pl.col.region == "Year").drop("region").to_dict(as_series=False),
    key=lambda x: x[1]
)

df.select(["region"] + cols)

shape: (4, 5)
┌────────┬────────┬───────┬──────┬───────┐
│ region ┆ Ration ┆ Share ┆ Lots ┆ Stake │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---   ┆ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ str    ┆ i64    ┆ i64   ┆ i64  ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═══════╪══════╪═══════╡
│ EU     ┆ 70     ┆ 99    ┆ 70   ┆ 80    │
│ ASIA   ┆ 4      ┆ 6     ┆ 4    ┆ 5     │
│ AMER   ┆ -10    ┆ -30   ┆ -10  ┆ -20   │
│ Year   ┆ 2019   ┆ 2020  ┆ 2018 ┆ 2021  │
└────────┴────────┴───────┴──────┴───────┘

